# Why does Javascript's console.log subtracts with - sign and concats with + sign?

Tags: javascript

So, here is the thing

`console.log('2' - '1')` prints 1 which is expected as the strings are converted to numbers and operated on - sign. But when `console.log('2' + '1')` is executed it prints 21 which is concatenation.Can someone explain what's the reasoning behind this behaviour ?

Comment: nothing to do with console...that's how js string concatenation works....`string+string=string` or `string + number = string`. No magic to it

Comment: Why there is a downvote ? It's a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two strings, you can concatenate them with `+`. This is not uncommon, many languages do that.

There is no `-` operator for strings. So when you use it, it reverts back to the existing `-` operator, which only works for numbers. And Javascript is trying to be helpful by converting the strings to numbers automatically. That is not as common, but it seems you expected it, so no surprise here.

If you want to convert a string (or something that might be a string) to a number, you can use `+x`. You need to convert both, because if either is a string, you get concatenation.

```
console.log( (+'2') + (+'1') );  // logs 3
```

Comment: I expected + to concatenate but not - to operate that way but now the confusion is clear.